# stopping setTimeout loop in my snake game?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a snake game, and when the snake hit the wall or itself, it still wont stop moving. I figured out if I used the clearTimeout(), it would help. but it didn't. 
Is there a way to stop the loop? or it is another issue?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    init();
});

var move;
function init() {
    board.initBoard();
    drawSnake();
    food.createFood();
}

function play() {
    $('.newGame').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.playgame').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    moveSnake();
    getSnakeDir();
}

function gameover() {
    clearTimeout(move);
    $('.newGame').css('visibility', 'visible');
}

function playGame() {
    $('#gameboard').empty();
    $('.newGame').hide();
    init();
    play();
}

var board = {
    DIM: 20,
    initBoard: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < board.DIM; i++) {
            var row = $('<div class="row-' + i + '"></div>');
            
            for (var j = 0; j < board.DIM; j++) {
                var col = ('<div class="col-' + j + '-' + i + '"></div>');
                $(row).append(col);
            }
            $("#gameboard").append(row);
        }
    }
}

var snake = {
    position: ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'],
    direction: 'r',
    speed: 200,
};

function drawSnake() {
    $('.col-10-10').addClass('snake');
    $('.col-11-10').addClass('snake');
}

function getSnakeDir() {
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        if (event.which == 38) {
            snake.direction = 'u';
        } else if (event.which == 39) {
            snake.direction = 'r';
        } else if (event.which == 40) {
            snake.direction = 'd';
        } else if (event.which == 37) {
            snake.direction = 'l';
        }
    });
}

function moveSnake() {
    var tail = snake.position.pop();
    $('.col-' + tail).removeClass('snake');

    var coords = snake.position[0].split('-');
    var x = parseInt(coords[0]);
    var y = parseInt(coords[1]);

    if (snake.direction == 'r') {
        x = x + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'd') {
        y = y + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'l') {
        x = x - 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'u') {
        y = y - 1;
    }
    
    var currentcoords = x + '-' + y;
    snake.position.unshift(currentcoords);

    $('.col-' + currentcoords).addClass('snake');

    //when snake eats food
    if (currentcoords == food.coords) {
        console.log('true');
        $('.col-' + food.coords).removeClass('food');
        snake.position.push(tail);
        food.createFood();
    }

    //game over
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > board.DIM || y > board.DIM) {
        gameover();
    
    }

    //if snake touch itself
    if (hitItself(snake.position) == true) {
        gameover();
    }
    
    move=setTimeout(moveSnake, 200);
}

var food = {
    coords: "",

    createFood: function() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM-1)) + 1;
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM-1)) + 1;
        var fruitCoords = x + '-' + y;
        $('.col-' + fruitCoords).addClass('food');
        food.coords = fruitCoords;
    },
}

function hitItself(array) {
    var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var value = array[i];
        if (value in valuesSoFar) {
            return true;
        }
        valuesSoFar[value] = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```css
.buttonnewgame {
     position: relative;
}

.newGame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 25%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: arial;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.gameContainer{
    width: 100%;
}

#gameboard {
    background-color:#eee;
    padding:3px;
}

.playgame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: arial;    
}

/* styling the board */
div[class^='row'] {
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

div[class*='col']{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

/*display the snake*/
.snake {

    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 99;
}

.food {
    background: red;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="game">
    <div class="buttonnewgame">
        <input type="button" name="new game" value="new game" class="newGame" onclick="playGame()" />
        <button class="playgame" onclick="play()">Play Game</button>
        <div class="gameContainer">
            <div id="gameboard">
                <!-- snake game in here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few problems, but here is the 'working version' (there are more bugs).

1) I renamed `drawSnake` to `createSnake`.  You weren't fully reinitializing the snake when you called `init()`.  The snakes position was not being reset in the previous `drawSnake` method, so it would seem like the game was not playable.

After that there were 2 more bugs.

2) You have to return after you call `gameOver` or the game never really ends does it?  Once you clear the timeout in `gameover`, you immediately set another Timeout for on the last line of `moveSnake()` because you didn't return once the game was over.  That lead to weird results that made it seem like the game was unresponsive.

3) You were using a combination of `visibility` `none` or `visible` and `$.hide()`.   `$.hide()` uses `display: none`, so when you tried to show it again with the `visibility` style change, its still `display: none` so the new game button would stop appearing.

My advice to any game coder is to learn how to separate the code that handles how the game works (logic of the game, how the clock ticks, initialization of game state, etc) , and how it is displayed (the html and css).  Modeling the game logic after a cleanly written system is easy to read and debug.  The code becomes harder to understand and modify when the display code is mixed in with game logic.  In theory, our game should work perfectly without any kind of rendering.  Then we could write a renderer that produces an HTML canvas, html DOM, text in the command line, or OpenGL.

Heres an old project I never finished that should illustrate a separation between model and view.

http://tando.us/ganix/ganix.htm

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    init();
});

var move;
function init() {
    board.initBoard();
    createSnake();
    food.createFood();
}

function play() {
    $('.newGame').hide();
    $('.playgame').hide();
    moveSnake();
    getSnakeDir();
}

function gameover() {
    clearTimeout(move);
    $('.newGame').show();
}

function playGame() {
    $('#gameboard').empty();
    $('.newGame').hide();
    init();
    play();
}

var board = {
    DIM: 20,
    initBoard: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < board.DIM; i++) {
            var row = $('<div class="row-' + i + '"></div>');
            
            for (var j = 0; j < board.DIM; j++) {
                var col = ('<div class="col-' + j + '-' + i + '"></div>');
                $(row).append(col);
            }
            $("#gameboard").append(row);
        }
    }
}

var snake = {
    position: ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'],
    direction: 'r',
    speed: 200,
};

function createSnake() {
    $('.col-10-10').addClass('snake');
    $('.col-11-10').addClass('snake');
    snake.position = ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'];
}

function getSnakeDir() {
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        if (event.which == 38) {
            snake.direction = 'u';
        } else if (event.which == 39) {
            snake.direction = 'r';
        } else if (event.which == 40) {
            snake.direction = 'd';
        } else if (event.which == 37) {
            snake.direction = 'l';
        }
    });
}

function moveSnake() {
    var tail = snake.position.pop();
    $('.col-' + tail).removeClass('snake');

    var coords = snake.position[0].split('-');
    var x = parseInt(coords[0]);
    var y = parseInt(coords[1]);

    if (snake.direction == 'r') {
        x = x + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'd') {
        y = y + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'l') {
        x = x - 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'u') {
        y = y - 1;
    }
    
    var currentcoords = x + '-' + y;
    snake.position.unshift(currentcoords);

    $('.col-' + currentcoords).addClass('snake');

    //when snake eats food
    if (currentcoords == food.coords) {
        console.log('true');
        $('.col-' + food.coords).removeClass('food');
        snake.position.push(tail);
        food.createFood();
    }

    //game over
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > board.DIM || y > board.DIM) {
        gameover();
        return;
    
    }

    //if snake touch itself
    if (hitItself(snake.position) == true) {
        gameover();
        return;
    }
    
    move=setTimeout(moveSnake, 200);
}

var food = {
    coords: "",

    createFood: function() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM-1)) + 1;
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM-1)) + 1;
        var fruitCoords = x + '-' + y;
        $('.col-' + fruitCoords).addClass('food');
        food.coords = fruitCoords;
    },
}

function hitItself(array) {
    var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var value = array[i];
        if (value in valuesSoFar) {
            return true;
        }
        valuesSoFar[value] = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```css
.buttonnewgame {
     position: relative;
}

.newGame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 25%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: arial;
}

.gameContainer{
    width: 100%;
}

#gameboard {
    background-color:#eee;
    padding:3px;
}

.playgame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: arial;    
}

/* styling the board */
div[class^='row'] {
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

div[class*='col']{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

/*display the snake*/
.snake {

    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 99;
}

.food {
    background: red;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="game">
    <div class="buttonnewgame">
        <input type="button" name="new game" value="new game" class="newGame" style="display:none;" onclick="playGame()" />
        <button class="playgame" onclick="play()">Play Game</button>
        <div class="gameContainer">
            <div id="gameboard">
                <!-- snake game in here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. And it worked! Just to note, I made this game about 5 months ago, before learning about the MVC. and you're right. its a mess of a code. but i'm trying to include it as it is for a portfolio to show flaws and progress. again, thank you :)

Comment: Working messy code is preferable over broken code.  You are on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

You could try not to initiate a new `setTimeout` call at the and of the `moveSnake` function, but instead using.

```
function play() {
    $('.newGame').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.playgame').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    move = setInterval(moveSnake, 200);
    getSnakeDir();

}
```

and remove the

```
move = setTimeout(moveSnake, 200)
```

from the `moveSnake` function and do

```
function gameover() {
    clearInterval(move);
    $('.newGame').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

Comment: I did that, and it worked. But the snake wont move after you click new game.

Comment: @Nordax, you will need to reset your game when the button is clicked and run the setTimeout function again

Comment: Thats what i did in the playGame() function. why it wont work?